# Jquery Assigning data-id, first value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have code which when i click on a button it appends the value of the button into a new paragraph tag, a data-id is also assigned to each tag at the same time, using a count.

```
   var count = 1;
   buttonValue = ($(this).val());
   var buttons = $( ".button-values" );
   buttonPara = $(".button-values p");
   var addData = $('<p>'+buttonValue+'</p>').attr('data-id', count++);
   addData.appendTo(buttons);
   var dataCount = buttonPara.last().attr('data-id');
   console.log(dataCount);
```

However when i look at the console the first item is showing as undefined and then the second item is showing as 1 and then the next 2 etc...

The p tag itself is however been assigned the correct data-id number, im not sure why this is happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get the collection of `p`:

```
buttonPara = $(".button-values p");
```

Then you add the new `p`:

```
var addData = $('<p>'+buttonValue+'</p>').attr('data-id', count++);
addData.appendTo(buttons);
```

Then you get the last `p` *from the collection generated before the latest `p` was added*:

```
var dataCount = buttonPara.last().attr('data-id');
```

The `buttonPara` variable doesn't update automatically when you add elements to the page. Try replacing

```
var dataCount = buttonPara.last().attr('data-id');
```

with

```
var dataCount = $(".button-values p").last().attr('data-id');
```

Comment: Lovely, that's done exactly what I need. Thanks so much for your help.